# bpy.app.translations.register gets "ValueError" on "translations message cache"

Tags: python, cache

I am adding translation into my addon using:

```
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)
    bpy.app.translations.register(__name__, translate.translation_dict)
```

It throws back a ValueError:

```
translations message cache already contains some data for addon '__main__'
```

[image]

Googled around but can't find anything similar. 
Can't figure out what it meant and how to dealt with.

Something to do with cached data that can be deleted?

Comment: If you are running this from the text editor then `__name__ == "__main__"` either install as an addon and reload the script or hardcode in your addon name to test.

Comment: It works now. Then, do I hv to remove this line of code when i actually package this addon for others to use? or do i just leave it there?

Comment: @batFINGER I tried to reload with F8, but still not working. I am using text editor inside Blender, what else should i check? I am running the `register()` inside `if __name__ == "__main__":`

Comment: If the addon is registered as an addon (when you enable an addon it is imported from the addon folder "the_addons_name",  then `__name__ == "the_addons_name"`   and henceforth `__name__ == "__main__" ` is false. It's True when run from text editor.  Have you tried calling `bpy.app.translations.unregister("__main__")` ?  ... you really want to be loading as an addon and not running from text editor.